# SPA + WebAPI authenticate using Azure AD B2C and Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, hello.js

My customer wants to use AZURE AD B2C to authenticate external users, and Azure AD for employees of his company. I've been looking on github and googling about it, but there's a lack of examples over there.

Does anybody had the same requirement to give some hints?

Besides that, it seems that MSAL.js / hello.js has some bugs (X-Frame-Options issue when renewing the token).

Is there any other JS library that I'm not familiar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My customer wants to use AZURE AD B2C to authenticate external users, and Azure AD for employees of his company.

Azure B2C supports this from custom policies. You can easily configure this by referring [Azure Active Directory B2C: Get started with custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) and [Azure Active Directory B2C: Sign in by using Azure AD accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom)

> Besides that, it seems that MSAL.js / hello.js has some bugs (X-Frame-Options issue when renewing the token).

Microsoft was written a sample application using [hello.js](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-hellojs-singlepageapp) library. But as you said it has **x-frame options issue but that is only for Social IDPs**. So, you can still use SPA app written from Microsoft for your use-case.

> Is there any other JS library that I'm not familiar?

Yes, there is another JS library out there similar to hello.js that is [oidc-client.js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). It is easy to configure and use in SPA application.

Comment: The X-Frame-Options issue is NOT a limitation of the library, it's a restriction enforced by the social identity provider. In other words, some social identity providers just do NOT support silent renewal of tokens in SPAs.

Comment: yes, you are right. Few of the IDPs (not exactly only social) doesn't support silent renewal. We can do have workaround for this by re-requesting same authorization request again in a new tab (when we request in a new tab it won't ask you to re-enter credentials and you can easily get new auth token). But requesting from tab doesn't work with Amazon IDP, Amazon still asks you to re-enter credentials.